# ADS Simulation of Half-Wave Rectifier

Tags: rf, simulation, rectifier, bridge-rectifier, ads

[image]

[image]

I’m trying to simulate a half wave rectifier for a -84dBm 2.4GHz AC signal.

The rectifier doesn’t seem to be giving me the correct waveform - the negative half cycle isn’t blocked?

Also sort of confused about how I’m supposed to pick the capacitance value.

Would appreciate any help and guidance.

Comment: Try 2MHz not GHz with these parts

Comment: How did you choose the diode, and what's its reverse recovery time? Also, try an input voltage comparable to its Vf, you surely can't expect it to rectify 50uVp-p.

Answer (score 1):

As @BrianDummond pointed out, Vf is way larger than your test voltage, the diode doesn't conduct at all.

Also the capacitance of the diode is maximum 2pF according to the datasheet for the BAS70, which corresponds to 33ohm@2.4GHz. In series with 10pF//50ohm, calculate the output voltage from that and you will probably figure out why you are seeing this amplitude at the output.

[image: Schematic, diode replaced with 2pF CAP]
[image: sim result]

Answer (score 0):

> The rectifier doesn’t seem to be giving me the correct waveform - the
> negative half cycle isn’t blocked?

The capacitor is the problem, you have made a nice low pass filter and the cap is filtering. Try 1pf

To pick the right value, you would need to find the equivalent series resistance of the diode, which will be hard because it changes.

Also if this is to be built in the real world, the simulation will not reflect reality unless you put in resistance of the traces on a PCB or resistance from wire that will be used between components. The cap is also probably ideal (with no ESR) so make sure the cap has ESR of a real capacitor (the ESR can be found in most datasheets for capacitors) and the capacitor and resistor should have a few nH of inductance in series with them (terminals on SMT or through hole devices have inductance that can make a difference in the GHz range.